# SharePoint, local sync and Excel linked workbooks

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, onedrive, offline-sync

We have a file share hosted in SharePoint Online, which users sync to their local PCs using the OneDrive desktop application.

What's the best way of managing links between Excel workbooks in this scenario?  As far as I can tell, the options are:

- Link to the locally synced file. Since the path to this tends to be different for each user, the links break for each user.  This depends somewhat on the relative path between the workbooks; sometimes Excel will keep track of a relative path between them and sometimes it won't.
- Link to the file on SharePoint Online - eg to `https://mycompany.sharepiont.com/sites/FileShare/Shared Documents/Folder1/File1.xlsx`.  This works but only if the user is online - it makes the locally-synced copy a lot less useful.

Have I missed another option?